# How to find the value of $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2},i):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2})]?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Determine  the splitting field   and its degree  over $\mathbb{Q}$  for $x^4+2$

**My attempt** :Obviously,the splitting  field  of the polynomial $f(x)=x^4 +2$ is  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2},i)$

So  the splitting field   of $f$ has degree  $$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2},i):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2},i):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2})] \cdot [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2}):\mathbb{Q}]$$

since $\sqrt[4]{-2}$ is a root of the irreducible polynomial $x^4+2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2}):\mathbb{Q}]=4$.

Here  im unable to find the value  of  $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2},i):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2})]$.

**My confusion**:  How to find the  value of  $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2},i):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2})]?$

Comment: $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2}):\mathbb{Q}] = 4$, not 2

Comment: okay@cos_dm_math21

Comment: You should also have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1231921/72031)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to find the roots explicitly. We have $$x^2=\pm\sqrt{2}i$$ and then $$x=\pm 2^{1/4}\cdot\frac{1+ i} {\sqrt{2} }, \pm 2^{1/4}\cdot\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2} }$$ Hence the splitting field here is $K=\mathbb{Q} (2^{1/4},i)$ and one can prove that it is of degree $8$ over $\mathbb{Q} $.

---

Here is a bit more detail to see why the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q} (2^{1/4},i)$. Consider the two roots $a, b$ given by $(1\pm i) /2^{1/4}$ then $$2^{1/4}=\frac{2}{a+b},i=\frac{a-b}{a+b}$$ and hence the splitting field $L$ must be such that $L\supseteq \mathbb {Q}(2^{1/4},i)$. On the other hand all the roots are contained in $\mathbb{Q} (2^{1/4},i)$ and hence we have $L=\mathbb {Q}(2^{1/4},i)$.

Expressing the field $L$ in this form allows us to deduce easily that $i\notin\mathbb {Q} (2^{1/4})$ (real vs complex) and thereby get the degree $[L:\mathbb {Q} (2^{1/4})]=2$ and finally $[L:\mathbb {Q}] =8$.

Answer (score 1):

To compute this degree, we need to find a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2}, i)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2}).$ The most obvious basis is $1, i.$ Indeed, this list is clearly spanning, and so the dimension is at most 2. Now we just need to show that the dimension of the vector space isn't one; but this is fairly simple, since $i$ is not  contained in the smaller field, and if the dimension was 1, then the two fields would be the same.

Comment: As in other answer herd, it is not obvious that $i\notin\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt[4]{-2})$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $i \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2})$. Since $i^2 = -1 \in \mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2})$, it follows that $$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2},i):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2})] = 2$$

Comment: Is $i\notin {\mathbb Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2})$ so obvious?

Comment: You're right @Pythagoras Infact, I'm having the same doubt.